# How do you look up python builtin documentation with intellij/pycharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

Say I have a file open and I know the type of a variable is a dict, but the editor doesn't know that. Is there a way I can navigate to dict documentation?

I tried search everywhere, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't changed your default keymap you can place your cursor on the variable from which you want its documentation and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> which opens a popup with the available documentation!

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> does not work for you, open File > Settings > Keymap and in the search bar search for "Quick Documentation" and use the listed hot-key mentioned there for that action!